# How to implement reverse geocoding on SQL Server 2008 (with spatial capabilities)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, spatial

Let's suppose I have a street shapefile loaded on SQL Server 2008.

- How can I implement a reverse geocode function (get an address from a lat/long pair)?
- What SQL Spatial functions can I use for that?
- Does it have a function that get the closest "feature" from a lat/long pair?

Comment: Can you use any mapping APIs or does it have to be SQL Server that gets you the address?

Comment: It must be written entirely on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The example I saw indicated that you would write a custom CLR procedure to geocode.  I assume it would be the same for reverse geocoding - pick a service, write the code and encapsulate in a SQL procedure.

Here is a method reference for the geography data type.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933802%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx